# Button "Step Back Over" always disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

While debugging in Visual Studio v16.3.2 I want to back on the previous breakpoint and I am trying to achieve it via `Step Back Over` button. Why this button always disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason **could** be that it's disabled in your IDE.

Try

```
Tools > Options > IntelliTrace > General
```

and in there make sure that “IntelliTrace events and snapshots” is checked.

This might or might not require a restart of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using correct configuration but link can help you setting.

[Step Back Debugging](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/step-back-while-debugging-with-intellitrace/)

Other possible reason could be, is step back allowed on variable assignments?